# Why is the Text widget 's line height changes from English to Chinese?

Tags: flutter

With this code

```
Center(
        child: Text(
          'hello 你好',
          style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red, fontSize: 24),
        ),
      )
```

It seems the Chinese will got a larger height than English ? Can i make them have a same height ?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18473 please check this issue.

Comment: Because different languages have different styles, including height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different text height is caused by different font family.

Would you change font that supports Chinese and English?
https://fonts.google.com/?subset=chinese-simplified&preview.text=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BDHello&preview.text_type=custom

Or if you want to make a text height same, below is the example.
Using 'strutStyle' parameter in Text, althouhg it is not convenient, you can modifying each text height is same.
https://medium.com/@najeira/control-text-height-using-strutstyle-4b9b5151668b
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38875

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Text(
            'hello 你好',
            style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red, fontSize: 24),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Text(
                "hello",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                ),
                strutStyle: StrutStyle(
                  height: 1.5,
                  fontSize: 24,
                ),
              ),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text(
                "你好",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                ),
                strutStyle: StrutStyle(
                  height: 1.5,
                  fontSize: 24,
                ),
              ),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```